# op amp level shifter no input situation

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, level-shifting

I tried out op-amp level shifters on web. The ones recomended here as well but there is a problem when no input applied. The output voltage is no seperable from the case voltage applied. As i understand it is called op-amp biasing. I am trying to apply reference voltage with shift voltage but calculation isnt simple. So i am guessing there is a commoon way to do it. 
How can i sense opamp level shifter has no inputs or how to bias that shifter?

[image: i am using that one (the popular one i guess)]

And my biasing idea is like that:

[image]

Comment: post an example circuit of what level shifter you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is disconnected, if that's what you mean by "no input", the output will not be midscale on the ADC. It will be indistinguishable from a 1.6V input.

You can deal with that by buffering the input (voltage follower) and adding a high-value resistor to ground on the input of the buffer, but you'd need power supplies higher than +/-5V for the buffer amplifier (how much higher depends on the op-amp used).

You can also apply a reference voltage other than ground to the left end of R1 in your top diagram, but it will have to be a **negative** reference voltage to shift the output above ground. That would allow a single op-amp with a single supply, but you need a negative reference voltage.

You could also add a resistor from the ADC input (right hand side of R? on your top diagram) to a positive reference, which would allow a single op-amp to be used again, but that op-amp would need a negative supply to allow the output to go to zero.

Comment: Thank you. yes that is what i mean.
all the answers require negative supply: That will change my design critically and cost will increase dramatically (because of isolated dc-dc converter).
i wonder if is there a way without negative supply

Comment: Create a negative supply with a charge pump, eg. 7660 or LTC has some good parts.

Comment: i will check if i can find cheap voltage inverter in my country. I may try No:3 of Dave's solutions: http://youtu.be/g7b5YZENvjY?t=28m16s